# How to define same path in all machins in Ubuntu using javascript for protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I want to define same path in Ubuntu like in Windows(User.dir)
so want is the soulution

currently am using like :

```
projectpath="/home/local/NEXTEDUCATION/**anandgoudp**/workspace/NextErp
```

which is a static, in place of **`anandgoudp`** i want to get the user name in which meching i have logged in.

Comment: How about `import getpass`,  `getpass.getuser()`?

Answer (score 0):

Using shell command `whoami` you can get the currently logged in user name. To execute a shell command using node js, you can use [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) npm module.

Example:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
var projectpath="/home/local/NEXTEDUCATION/{{username}}/workspace/NextErp";
var currentUserName = shell.exec("whoami").stdout.replace("\n","");
projectpath= projectpath.replace("{{username}}",currentUserName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution for my question.

```
var tr = process.platform;
var sub;
var projectpath, linuxpath;
const username = require('username');
var uname = username.sync();

projectpath = "/home/local/NEXTEDUCATION/" + uname + "/workspace/NextErp";
```